# i was following a script but my count function still resulted in an error

Tags: google-bigquery, count

why did my query didnt run with the COUNT function in SQL? COUNT(*) as num_trips,

```
SELECT 
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ",end_station_name) AS route
  COUNT(*) as num_trips, 
  ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
 FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
  GROUP BY 
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

When something "didn't run" there is usually an error message. In future questions please include the complete error message. Here is what I think might have gone wrong.

There is a comma missing  between "**AS route**" and "**COUNT(*)**"

For a number of reasons, including this one, I have always preferred a "comma first" approach to SQL format, like this. It is almost impossible to avoid including the correct commas this way e.g:

```
SELECT
      usertype
    , CONCAT (start_station_name, ' to ', end_station_name) AS route
    , COUNT(*) AS num_trips
    , ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration AS int64) / 60), 2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery - PUBLIC - data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
      usertype
    , start_station_name
    , end_station_name
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10;
```